# Powershell commands not working in Build Events in Visual Studio

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013

When I run a file through the **Build Events in Visual Studio** I get the same error for EVERY in-built powershell command I try.

**The build events window in Visual Studio**

[image]

**The error**

> ------ Build started: Project: XAzure, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>    XAzure-> C:\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\bin\XAzure.dll
>
> *Get-Date : The term 'Get-Date' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*
>
> At C:\visual studio 2013\Projects\XAzure\WaitForFiles.ps1:3 char:15
>    + **$dateTime = $(Get-Date)**
>    +               ~~~~~~~~
>        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Date:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

The file only contains this one line *$dateTime = $(Get-Date)* and fails.

It *does not matter* what command I run

- Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
- Write-Output
- Get-Date
- etc.

But if I switch out Get-Date for e.g

```
$start =[System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss.fff")
```

it works just fine. But that is no solution.

I´m firing this up in the Build Events with

```
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -File "$(ProjectDir)WaitForFiles.ps1" "$(ProjectDir)\"
```

But I have also tried number of other variations like (can´t remeber them all)

```
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "$(ProjectDir)WaitForFiles.ps1" "$(ProjectDir)\"
```

**Runing this file in a powershell window works just fine** so I must have the commands but not in the build events.

I´m running *Visual Studio 2013 update 4 in **admin mode*** on a win32 Windows 8.1 i7 Dell Laptop.

Running *$psversiontable* gives me

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34014
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17090
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

I have tried to give powershell more access and elevated privileges but nothing has worked.

I can´t think of anything more to add to this question or to try. I googled this for 3 hours this weekend and tried everything that I could find on this error with out success.

The strange thing is that there are lots of this "*The term 'x' is not recognized..*" error out there with seemingly totally different causes.

**Update 1**

I have tried to explicitly "install" Microsoft.PowerShell.Utiltiy (in a admin Powershell window ) with this command 
    Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility

but I get this error

> *Import-Module : The specified module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.*

If I run $env:PSModulePath I get

> c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\PowershellModules;
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement

**BUT** if I run %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules 
I find *C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules*

**Does that mean that the this set of modules are not connected somehow?** I see the Microsoft.PowerShell.Utiltiy folder there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. The commands that were failing were all from  **Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility**. Just as Jisaak pointed out (give you 1 up for that thanks)

After I found that ps1 file ( Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.ps1) and looked into it I saw *PowerShellVersion="3.0"*.

Since Im running PowerShell version 4.0 I needed to downgrade the version Im running.

First I thought that Version -3 would do the trick but for some reason that was not an option. But by adding **-Version 2** switch everything works fine.

So the following works

```
Powershell -Version 2 -ExecutionPolicy  bypass -File "$(ProjectDir)WaitForFiles.ps1" "$(ProjectDir)\"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
cmd /c powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file "$(ProjectDir)WaitForFiles.ps1"
```

Get-Date cmdlet is in the Microsoft.Powershell.Utility module. Maybe you could try to load it explicit:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
```

Comment: I have tried the first one without luck. Are you then talking about explicitly importing the module in the WaitForFiles.ps1 file? I tried but failed. But if you are talking about doing Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility in powersell I get the error message "The specified module ''was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module direcotry. But I can enter Get-date and get a date. Updating the question.

Comment: I tried to add the  location to the Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility to the PSModulePath without luck. But when I open up the Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.ps1 I see "PowerShellVersion="3.0"" Does that matter? Im running 4.0

Answer (score 1):

I had more luck with this answer:

[PowerShell script result different when ran from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546488/powershell-script-result-different-when-ran-from-visual-studio)

I believe running powershell from visual studio launches the x86 version. Hardcoding the path to...

%WINDIR%\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe

... made it work, especially since my script had V4 commmands.